# HTML not passing validation

Tags: java, java-ee-6

The below line is not passing validation in my application.  The error is in Netbeans is...

`Bad value "     /content/edit" for attribute href on element "a": WHITESPACE in PATH`

```
    <a href="<%=request.getAttribute("urlPrefix")%>/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

The runtime error is:

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /base.jsp(9,25) PWC6213: quote symbol expected`

I am passing an attribute for this value.  Why am I getting this error when I pass a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use scriptlets in JSP. Use the JSP EL:

```
<a href="${urlPrefix}/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

Comment: But don't forget to protect against [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A2-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Comment: @Asaph: agreed, but how is it specific to this solution? All the other suggestions are as safe (or unsafe) as mine. It all depends what is in urlPrefix and where it comes from.

Comment: Sorry to pick on your answer specifically but I thought it was worth a mention. I could have left that comment on any other answer I suppose (but didn't want to leave it on _every_ other answer). I usually point out incidental XSS and SQL injection whenever I see it. I think raising awareness is worthwhile. It makes the web a safer place.

Comment: And BTW: yours is not the only answer I've left a comment on. No one was spared as I think no one actually answered the question. I've just added [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8697964/166339) which I think moves things along in a more productive direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<%=request.getAttribute('urlPrefix')%>/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

Use single quotes with `urlPrefix`. It should work.

Comment: I doubt it. This is a scriptlet, not an el expression.

Comment: Agree with Asaph, it should be written <a href='<%=request.getAttribute("urlPrefix")%>/content/edit'>Add Content</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% String urlPrefix = (String)request.getAttribute("urlPrefix"); %>
<a href="<%=urlPrefix%>/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

or better this:

```
<%
String urlPrefix = (String)request.getAttribute("urlPrefix");
String url = urlPrefix + "/content/edit";
%>
<a href="<%=url%>">Add Content</a>
```

or even better use EL:

```
<a href="${urlPrefix}/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

It's worth mentioning the protection against [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A2-Cross-Site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) as [Asaph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166339/asaph) pointed out in his comment:

```
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(urlPrefix)}/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

might do the trick if you include

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

at the top of your JSP.

Comment: The last one doesn't use the JSTL. It uses JSP EL. And param is used to access request parameters, not request attributes. ${urlPrefix} is sufficient.

Comment: @JBNizet - My bad, thank you for the correction. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Murat: I applaud you for _trying_ to protect against XSS but `fn:escapeXml()` won't protect you in an `href` attribute. Imagine that `urlPrefix` contains the value `javascript:alert('you are so XSSed!'); //`. The xml encoding doesn't do anything to the colon character and thus any javascript appearing after it will be executed by the browser. The correct approach is to validate that `urlPrefix` is a valid url prefix in the given context. Whitelist validation would be ideal. See the [OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

I've just done a simple test and the following line has no syntax error and runs without throwing an exception whether the `urlPrefix` attribute is set or not:

```
<a href="<%=request.getAttribute("urlPrefix")%>/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

There is no syntax error at all. In the case of there being no `urlPrefix` attribute set, the resulting html is:

```
<a href="null/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

In the case of `urlPrefix` being equal to `http://example.com`, the resulting html is:

```
<a href="http://example.com/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

Here is a quick little standalone `test.jsp` file to demonstrate:

```
<% request.setAttribute("urlPrefix", "http://example.com"); %>
<a href="<%=request.getAttribute("urlPrefix")%>/content/edit">Add Content</a>
```

You can remove the first line to test the `null` case.

So we've demonstrated that the line you posted as the alleged offending line is not actually problematic. Some possibilities:

1. Are you sure you're looking at the correct line?
2. Are you sure you're looking at the correct file?
3. Are you sure you've deployed your application?
4. Are you sure you're looking at the correct url/environment?